# Is there any alternative for MPNS in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I want to support push notification for my Windows Phone app. Is there any alternative for Microsoft Push Notification Service? Something like MQTT etc. I have a similar app in Android where MQTT is used to send push notifications. I need the same service to be implemented for Windows Phone. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

WP does not allow your app to keep a socket connections alive while you are in background.
So this is not possible.

> Your only option would be to have a background agent that contacts your server each time it runs (approximately every half hour) and checks for new messages.  If there are messages, use a local toast notification to alert the user.  If the user taps on the toast, it will launch your app.
>
> If it is only new data that you need to pull down, then push
>   notifications were never going to work because all they can do is
>   display a toast and the user has to tap the toast to launch the app
>   for it to do anything.  The background agent is still your best bet
>   here and poll for new data every time it runs.  If the data will take
>   a while to pull down, use background file transfer to pull the data
>   down to isolated storage, then process it when the agent or the app
>   runs next.

Comment: So MPNS is the only recommended way to implement Push notifications in Windows Phone? You mentioned that I can send request to server every 30 sec in background. But WP does not allow running background services when another application is running at the foreground. So how can I send request to server at background without using MPNS?

Comment: So I think this is not possible.

Comment: I just found out that there are background agents in Windows Phone which I can use.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: Now I need to find out if I can use Background agents to implement push notifications or not. Please let me know if you get some idea.

Comment: Anybody knows what Facebook and Gmail apps does? Are they using MPNS for push notifications?

Comment: Can anybody please tell me what Push notification mechanism Facebook and gmail apps supports in Windows Phone?